# mke2fs command creating a ext2 FS on a partition when -t type option is set to ext4

Tags: partitioning

I ran the following command on a newly created partition

```
 mke2fs -v -t ext4 -i 32768 -b 4096 -O 'extents,^has_journal,dir_index,flex_bg' -I 128 -G 64 /dev/sdf1
```

Post this when i check the details using parted command i see its a ext2 File system

```
parted /dev/sdf print
Model: ATA ST2000NM0033-9ZM (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdf: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      2097kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ext2

root@a104-81-59-76:~#
```